# Fallback function in Solidity

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

I have seen many examples of the **fallback** function in Solidity, but I didn't understand any of them. Also, I've seen references to the **payable** modifier. My questions are:

1. What exactly does the `fallback()` function do?
2. Does this function take arguments?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

First, `payable` is a modifier that can be added to a function. What you are most likely misinterpreting is a use case like:

```
function () public payable {}
```

It's impossible to have `payable()` as a function name as it is a reserved keyword. You may use `payable` only in addition to existing functions like:

```
function deposit() payable {}
function register(address sender) payable {}
```

Second, `payable` allows a function to receive ether while being called as stated in [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#function-modifiers). It's mandatory to include the `payable` keyword from Solidity 0.4.x. If you try to send ether using [call](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-does-p-recipient-call-value-p-amount-p-data-do), as follows:

```
token.foo.call.value("ETH_TO_BE_SENT")("ADDITIONAL_DATA")
```

to a function without a `payable` keyword, the transaction will be rejected.

Usually, there is a no name function to accept ether to be sent to a contract which is called a [fallback](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function) function:

```
function () payable {}
```

But you may have more than one `payable` annotated functions that are used to perform different tasks, like registering a deposit to your contract:

```
function deposit() payable {
  deposits[msg.sender] += msg.value;
};
```

Comment: you mean payable() is fallback function ? According to Solidity document fallback function is that function which avoid from accident of transaction to unknown contract. Please make me clear .

Comment: Thx for spotting that. I've misspelt it in a hurry, it's all corrected now.

Comment: you mean   without ,  p.recipient.call.value(p.amount)(p.data) , payable() function cannot be called?

Comment: The fallback function is mandatory for contracts to be able to receive ether transfers from solidity 0.4.x. Then, if you always throw inside this function your contract won't be able to accept any ether - preventing accidental sending. If you leave the body empty or add any non-throwing code you will keep the ether on contract balance. I hope it answers your question?

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct . But what if in the case of payable() ?

Comment: I've moved the content from discussion to the answer. Let me know if it's clear and helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 37):

### Update for Solidity ^0.6.0

There have been major changes to the way the fallback function is defined.

From the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/060-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes):

> The unnamed function commonly referred to as “fallback function” was split up into a new fallback function that is defined using the fallback keyword and a receive ether function defined using the receive keyword.

What you have to do is replace this:

```
function () external [payable] { ... }
```

With this:

```
receive() external payable { ... }
```

Or this:

```
fallback() external [payable] { ... }
```

In most cases, you should implement only `receive`. As per the docs:

> You should only need to implement the new `fallback` function if you are following an upgrade or proxy pattern.

### Diagram

Here's a nice diagram from the [solidity-by-example.org](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/) website that explains what fallback function is called based on calldata:

```
Which function is called, fallback() or receive()?

        send Ether
            |
        msg.data is empty?
            /       \
          yes        no
          /           \
 receive() exists?     fallback()
        /     \
    yes        no
    /           \
receive()      fallback()
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes!

Comment: In which cases msg.data could be empty?

Comment: @sametcodes when you send ETH without passing any calldata

Answer (score 12):

When someone transfers funds to your contract, the function with `payable` modifier executes automatically. Here is an example of a `payable` function.

```
contract token {    
  function () payable {
    create(msg.sender);
  }
  function create(address _beneficiary) payable{
    uint256 amount = msg.value;
    /// your logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer did not make me clear. You make a loop .

Comment: so do both the fallback function and the create function gets called at the same time (since they both have `payable`)? So create gets called twice?

Comment: Payable is a *modifier*, not a function.

As a modifier, it explicitly *allows* the function to receive ether.  With out it, a function throws if a value of ether is sent in the transaction.  It is used to permission or prevent intentional and accidental value transfers.

Answer (score 12):

> What exactly does payable() function do? Does this function take arguments?

`payable()` does not exist anymore in Solidity 0.8.x

Modifier `payable` indicates if you can send an amount of ETH when executing a function.

Also, [Solidity 0.8.0 has breaking changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/080-breaking-changes.html?highlight=payable#new-restrictions):

- `address payable` is not a type anymore. Only `address` will be.
- `payable(address)` will ensure an address will be payable.
- `payable(0)` is valid and is an exception.

Answer (score 9):

Each function with the *payable* modifier can receive funds. But what if funds are sent to your contract to a non *payable* function? For this the fallback payable function was defined, which can receive funds in any case funds are sent to the contract.
This is why can see in many contracts some version of a function with **noname** and a payable modifier. 
Notice - this is a fallback *payable* function. But *payable* is not the function name, it has no name, its the function modifier.

```
function *noname* () payable { }
```

Answer (score 0):

payable is a function modifier means it checks if a certain condition is met before starting to execute a function.

the condition for a payable modifier is that the msg.value should not be null. means the transactions must contain some ether. any functions with the payable() as the modifier will only execute if the transaction has some ethers.

and for the parameters as far as I know payable() does not create any parameters

Comment: That is not correct, you can still execute a payable function sending 0 ethers, for example if the function doesn't do anything with `msg.value`. Check the accepted answer.