# What is the receive keyword in solidity?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function, solidity-0.6.x, keyword, receive

Solidity has a `receive` keyword. What is it and how do I use it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`receive` is a new keyword in Solidity 0.6.x that is used as a fallback function that is only able to receive ether.

- `receive() external payable` — for empty calldata (and any value)
- `fallback() external payable` — when no other function matches (not even the receive function). Optionally `payable`.

---

#### Long Answer

Solidity  0.6.x introduced the [`receive` keyword](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/060-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes)  in order to make contracts more explicit when their fallback functions are called. The `receive` method is used as a fallback function in a contract and is called when ether is sent to a contract *with no calldata*. If the `receive` method does not exist, it will use the `fallback` function.

From [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function):

> A contract can have at most one `receive` function, declared using `receive() external payable { ... }` (without the `function` keyword). This function cannot have arguments, cannot return anything and must have `external` visibility and `payable` state mutability. It is executed on a call to the contract with empty calldata. This is the function that is executed on plain Ether transfers (e.g. via .send() or .transfer()). If no such function exists, but a payable fallback function exists, the fallback function will be called on a plain Ether transfer. If neither a receive Ether nor a payable fallback function is present, the contract cannot receive Ether through regular transactions and throws an exception.

To use it, you  can include it in your contract in the following way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

// This contract keeps all Ether sent to it with no way
// to get it back.
//  This is example code. Do not use it in production.
contract Sink {
    event Received(address, uint);
    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

When evaluating whether  to use `receive` or `fallback`, consider the following:

This is why in version 0.6.x, the fallback function was split into two separate functions:

- `receive() external payable` — for empty calldata (and any value)
- `fallback() external payable` — when no other function matches (not even the receive function). Optionally `payable`.

This separation provides an alternative to the fallback function for contracts that want to receive plain ether.

**Edit based on Ismael's comment**: The 2300 gas stipend required by `.send()` and `.transfer()` apply to `receive()` in the same way that they apply to `.transfer()`. Additionally, contracts compiled with pre-0.6.0 solc versions are able to interact with the `receive()` function.

Additional information can be found in the Ethereum blog post [here](https://solidity.ethereum.org/2020/03/26/fallback-receive-split/).

Comment: Are these functions subject to gas stipend of 2300 gas? Are they compatible with previous versions of solidity? ie a contract compiled with an old version solc will be able to make a transfer to contracts compiled with 0.6?

Comment: The 2300 gas stipend is a limitation of `send` and `transfer`, not of the fallback function. With that said, the 2300 gas stipend behaves the same from the perspective of both `fallback()` and `receive()`.

Comment: And yes, older contracts (pre 0.6.x) can interact with new contracts that have the receive function. 

The following gist is what I used to test your questions:
https://gist.github.com/shanefontaine/5bd2a40f6d967748710850d61ebf1bbf

Comment: It should be noted that if fallback() gets triggered because no receive() method exists, then in that case fallback() is restricted to 2300 gas, even if .call() was used to send ether.

Comment: still confused about when we should use receive or fallback :v

Comment: @Ender see my [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78374/24693).

Comment: What does "no calldata" mean? Is that not a normal way to send ether to a contract then? Is it the recommended way to receive ether? Where does the received ether go? This answer is quoting the docs but they aren't very noob friendly