# What are the flaws of this example contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging, solidity-0.6.x

I am currently writing a paper/article on tokenization, in the beginning of which I introduce smart contracts.
To this end, I present the following contract as an example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SplitPot {
  address payable[] beneficiaries = [
    0x498898b3F52DAba1bB304a4b4D2EA31a111484B1,
    0xAcb19c763EB67ea757Efd8Cd8b6ecceb28F1284B,
    0xD5d3f3650C4DdE7B8034671129443A596Ce8ed57
  ];

  receive() external payable {
    uint individualAmount = msg.value / beneficiaries.length;

    for (uint i = 0; i < beneficiaries.length; i++) {
      beneficiaries[i].transfer(individualAmount);
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, the purpose of the contract is to evenly distribute all Ether sent to it among the three beneficiaries (all of which are testnet accounts I created). It works on testnet.

For this specific purpose, i.e., explaining what smart contracts are, I believe this is a **very good contract**:

- It is very short and easy to understand.
- It does something that is usually facilitated by a trusted third party -- which is now obsolete.

I also know this is a **very bad contract**, as it has severe shortcomings. For example: What if a transaction fails? Afaik, the beneficiaries have no way of recovering their share of Ether, and the contract doesn't re-attempt to send it to them. Also: I don't know whether the contract would execute correctly on mainnet, too.

I want to inform my readers that this is, in fact, a flawed contract, and I want to let them know what specifically can go wrong. As I just started learning about Ethereum, **I'd be very thankful if you helped me identifying these flaws** -- especially with regards to gas economics and coding style.

The paper/article will be licensed CC BY-SA 4.0, so I am not asking for help on commercial work!

Comment: You should make sure that function `receive` cannot be re-entered (for example, by requiring that a boolean state variable is false at the beginning of the function, then setting it to true, then setting it back to false at the end of the function).

Comment: You should also add `function` before `receive() external payable`, but I guess that's just a typo of yours.

Comment: @goodvibration Would you clarify what you mean by "re-enter" and put that along with both your comments in an answer? I'd accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that function `receive` cannot be re-entered, for example:

```
contract SplitPot {
    ...

    bool private locked = false;

    function receive() external payable {
        require(!locked, "reentrancy attempted");
        locked = true;
        ... // put your actual code here
        locked = false;
    }
}
```

Note that you seem to have forgotten declaring `function` prior to `receive() external payable` in your code, and that I have added it here.

---

**Explaining the reentrancy-protection:**

Your function executes `beneficiaries[i].transfer(individualAmount);`.

If `beneficiaries[i]` is the address of a contract, then the fallback function of that contract will be invoked; subsequently, that function can call your function and abuse its intended goal.

---

**Update:**

Following the comment by @blockrookie, the `receive` keyword was introduced in solc 0.6.x.

The unnamed function commonly referred to as “fallback function” was split up into a new fallback function that is defined using the `fallback` keyword and a receive ether function defined using the `receive` keyword.

Both functions are declared without the `function` keyword, hence my note above ("you seem to have forgotten declaring `function` prior to `receive() external payable` in your code") is relevant under solc 0.5.x or lower, but not under solc 0.6.x or higher.

More details about this function/keyword can be found [in the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function).

Comment: Thank you so much, @goodvibration! Could you clarify what you mean by "re-enter"? As I understand your code, the function can now only be executed once at a time, since it's locked during execution. But why did you do that? How would someone be able to abuse the contract if there were no such lock?

Comment: @blockrookie: Done; see updated answer.

Comment: Hey, @goodvibration, I believe the function keyword should actually not be present in this case, at least according to my understanding of the latest docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/contracts.html#receive-ether-function

Comment: @blockrookie: Interesting! This seems to be a new feature of solc 0.6.x, which was not available up until (and including) solc 0.5.x. A good description of it, as well as the difference between that function and the fallback function, is available in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/81995/16043).