# Getting an error in attempting to write a withdrawAll function to remove any tokens that get sent to a contract

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

I am using remix: I have this function in my contract:

```
contract Control {
address public owner;
address public newOwner;

event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

function Owned() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}


modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function withdrawAll() public payable onlyOwner {
    require(payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance));
}

}
```

But I'm getting this error with the withdrawAll function:

```
test token V2.sol:84:17: ParserError: Expected primary expression. 
require(payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance)); ^-----^
```

did i forget a varible or is this just a syntax error? The script works, but this function I just want to be able to call to withdraw anything that gets stuck at this address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the `withdrawAll` function work, you have first to call the method `Owned` to set the `owner` address.

However, your contract is currently useless. In fact, it cannot receive ethers as it does not include a [receive](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/what-is-the-receive-keyword-in-solidity) function. Also please note that `send` only allows to send ethers, and not tokens stucked on the smart contract. Furthermore `address(this).balance` refers to the contract ether balance.

You can try this code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Control {
address public owner;
address public newOwner;

event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

function Owned() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}


modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}


constructor() payable {
    
}


function withdrawAll() public payable onlyOwner {
    require(payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance));
}


receive() external payable { 
    }
    
}
```

After compiling you can follow these steps in Remix to test the smart contract :

1. Go to the deployment tab and choose one of the available account.
2. Fill the field "VALUE" to send some ethers to your contract during the deployment. Note the `payable` keyword on the constructor which allows us to do this.
3. Deploy the contract
4. Call the function `Owned` to set the owner
5. Call the function `withdrawAll` (with the same account) to retrieve all the ethers held by the smart contract.