# How to transfer ether within contracts?

Tags: ether, address.call

When I use the `toAddress.call{value: amt}("");` code, it works fine to transfer ether to EOA account but comes back false if its sent to contract. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a contract can't receive Ethers and will refuse the send.

For a contract to be able to receive Ethers, you should have a function with the `payable` keyword (and call that function), or use the generic fallback `receive` function. More info at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/81995/31933