# My contract fails to receive value (MATIC)

Tags: metamask, polygon, wei

I have a problem in sending 0.01 MATIC to the smart contract, I always get the not enough funds error:
[image]

the called function (createBid) is payable in the smart contract and here is the code:

[image]

I tried many values in the input but that doesn't work (only "0"), any help please ? (I'm new in blockchain and polygone tesnet)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implemented a payable fallback method, or use the `receive` function.

[What is the receive keyword in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/what-is-the-receive-keyword-in-solidity)

Comment: thanks for answering, the problem is solved by adding the options parameter in amount .