# How the fallback and receive functions in version 8 differ from fallback function in version 5 of Solidity?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

I found that in version 8, we explicitly use the keyword fallback for fallback function and there is a receive function also. Consider the following code:

```
receive() external payable {
...
}
fallback() external {
...
}
```

I have some questions:

> 1.The documentation at:[link of version 8 documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/solidity/develop/solidity.pdf) says that do not include white space in the receive and fallback
> functions.Kindly explain.
>
> 2.Can we use both receive() and fallback() functions for sending and receiving ether?

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Hey! 
check this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/payable-function-in-solidity/78374#78374) and this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/what-is-the-receive-keyword-in-solidity/81995#81995) for your 2nd question. In most cases, you will only need to implement `receive`.

Comment: For the first question it means that there should be no spaces between the function name and the parenthesis: `receive()` <-- good,  `receive  ()` <-- bad.