# Solidity - why does fallback() get called even though address.call{value:msg.value}("") does not have data?

Tags: solidity

The following contract calls another contract using an interface method (code to change):

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

interface MyStorage {
    function setStorageValue(uint256) external;
}

contract StorageFactory {
  uint256 storageValue;

  constructor(uint256 _storageValue) {
    storage = _storageValue;
  }

  function initStorage(MyStorage store) public payable {
    store.setStorageValue(storageValue);
    address payable storeAddress = payable(address(store));
    storeAddress.call{value: msg.value}("");
  }
}
```

Following is the StorageContract (code cannot be changed):

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Storage {

  int _storageValue;

  function setStorageValue(int storageValue) public {
    _storageValue = storageValue;
  }

  receive() external payable {
    require(_storageValue == -1 || address(this).balance <= uint(_storageValue), "Invalid storage value");
  }

  fallback() external {
    _storageValue = -1;
  }
}
```

I use a test to call initStorage of the first contract by passing a Storage object, where the test is meant to fail because the value is set to a large amount. But somehow, the fallback() function seems to get called, setting the value to -1. I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [payable() function In solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/payable-function-in-solidity)

Comment: I don't see how. It's just a clarification of "payable" as a modifier, and usage of call inside a payable function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `StorageFactory.initStorage` calls `setStorageValue(uint256)` and in your contract you declare it as `setStorageValue(int256)` (the input type is different).

For solidity they are completely different functions, so the `Storage` contract calls the fallback function because `setStorageValue(uint256)` isn't present.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was indeed the case, which I noticed before, but the problem was that I wasn't validating the returned success message, and so the test wasn't failing. Made me notice that this time :)