# fallback not executing

Tags: solidity, hardhat, delegatecall, fallback-function

I have a test project with proxy pattern (fallback/delegate call). The purpose is to have upgradeable contracts.
Here is the proxy contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract StorageContract {

    address private implementation;

    function setImplementation(address storageimplementation) external
    {
        implementation = storageimplementation;
    }


    fallback() external
    {
        console.log("executing fallback-------");
        delegate(implementation);
    }

    function delegate(address a) internal
    {
        assembly
        {
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())

            let result := delegatecall(gas(), a, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)

            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())

            switch result
            case 0
            {
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
            default
            {
                return(0, returndatasize())
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Implementation contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract StorageImplementation
{

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) public returns (uint256)
    {
        console.log("add function called");
        return a+b;
    }

    function hello() public returns (string memory)
    {
        console.log("hello function called");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Test:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Storage", function () {
  it("delegatecall test", async function () {
   const StorageContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("StorageContract");
   const storage = await StorageContract.deploy();
   await storage.deployed();

   const StorageImplementation = await ethers.getContractFactory("StorageImplementation");
   const storageImpl = await StorageImplementation.deploy();
   await storageImpl.deployed();

   storage.setImplementation(storageImpl.address);

   let impl = await storage.getImplementation();
   console.log("impl:" + impl);

    let helloResp = await storage.hello();

    expect(helloResp).to.equal("hello");
  });
});
```

**Fallback function is not executing** when I call a function that does not exist in the contract.

After executing tests via *npx hardhat test* I get an error:

> TypeError: storage.hello is not a function

And the **log message in fallback is not printed.**

I have also tried using receive function and payable modifier with fallback but it didn't help.

I hope I was clear enough.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [payable() function In solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/payable-function-in-solidity)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I tried with payable modifier, also with receive function as well. From what I've read it is possible that hardhat test checks the abi and returns an error without even giving fallback a chance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails because the abi of StorageContract has no `hello` function. So ethers.js doesn't populate the storage object with a `hello` function, and your call to `storage.hello()` fails.

You are on the good track given that `storage` is indeed a proxy for `storageImpl`, you only need to let ethers "know" about it. One way of solving it is to create an instance of `storageImplementation` attached to the address of `storage` :

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Storage", function () {
  it("delegatecall test", async function () {
    const StorageContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("StorageContract");
    const storage = await StorageContract.deploy();
    await storage.deployed();

    const StorageImplementation = await ethers.getContractFactory(
      "StorageImplementation"
    );
    const storageImpl = await StorageImplementation.deploy();
    await storageImpl.deployed();

    storage.setImplementation(storageImpl.address);

    let impl = await storage.getImplementation();
    console.log("impl:" + impl);

    // Proxy handle : StorageImplementation attached to storage address
    // Trough proxy, you can interact with storage as if it was an instance
    // of StorageImplementation.
    const proxy = await StorageImplementation.attach(storage.address);
    let helloResp = await proxy.hello();

    expect(helloResp).to.equal("hello");
  });
});
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. This is like casting the Storage contract to StorageImplementation. Do you maybe know the equivalent to attach in web3js?

Comment: Yeah you could see it that way. For Web3.js an optional `address` is  included in the constructor arguments (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract) just give the ABI of the implementation and the address of the proxy. Something like `new web3.eth.Contract(IMPLEMENTATION_ABI, proxy.address)` should work.