# how import in remix smart contract without source code?

Tags: fallback-function, reentrant-attacks, code

I am trying to call a fallback function on a smart contract that has not verified contract source code, How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending upon whether you pass some wei and/ or whether you pass data, a different fallback function may be triggered. See my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78374/24693).

Comment: in case of wei transfer, activation of internal reserve payment where eth will be returned, is that true?